# How can I get CasperJS and PhantomJS to play nicely on Yosemite?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, osx-yosemite, casperjs

I've been experiencing some issues getting CasperJS and PhantomJS to work on my Mac Pro running Yosemite and was wondering if anyone had any insights?

I've npm'd CasperJS globally and downloaded PhantomJS2 to my drive as per the instructions, but I keep getting errors like:

> [1]    9409 killed     casperjs test/casper/test.js

How can I get them to work together?

Comment: That's probably because CasperJS 1.1-beta3 doesn't support PhantomJS 2 (it's hardcoded to use only versions 1.8.2 - 1.x).

Comment: Note that I answered my own question :) I just thought since I've spent the better part of 4 hours working through the solution I'd spare someone else going through the same issue the hassle. But, yes, you're correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a tricky issue and the solution will involve going round the houses a little bit, but this is what I've found works:

1) [Use the instructions from the CasperJS documentation](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/installation.html#installing-from-git) to clone the repository from GitHub:

```
$ git clone git://github.com/n1k0/casperjs.git
$ cd casperjs
$ ln -sf `pwd`/bin/casperjs /usr/local/bin/casperjs
```

2) Download [this patched copy Mac copy of PhantomJS from GitHub](https://github.com/eugene1g/phantomjs/releases) and unzip it somewhere convenient. I added mine to a folder inside my app test folder as I only need it for that app, but you can put it anywhere.

3) Export the path of the binary you've just unzipped. In my case it would be something like[1]:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/Andy/Development/app/test/bin
```

And that should do the trick.

[1] [solution taken from this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19476947/casperjs-does-not-find-phantomjs)