# Casperjs installation issue on windows : ERROR - Fatal: No such file or directory; did you install phantomjs?

Tags: javascript, windows, phantomjs, automated-tests, casperjs

I am getting issue in casperjs installation on **windows**:

Hi have downloaded latest casperjs. Extracted it and added its bin path in  Path Environment variables. I have also phantomjs and I am successfully able to verify phantom js execution via **phantomjs -v**

But while I am doing **casperjs --version** on cmd I am getting following issue:

```
ERROR - Fatal: No such file or directory; did you install phantomjs?
```

Comment: if you can prefer to use chrome and firefox headless mode for more realistic results, today most of the tests frameworks can use them natively

Comment: Casperjs is dependent of PanthomJs is that being installed?

Comment: Yeah thats done

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19476947/casperjs-does-not-find-phantomjs more information here..

Comment: @PraveenGovind - link shared is pertaining to unix , linux , mac. I am looking for windows guide

Comment: Looks like casperjs doesn't know the correct path of phantomjs

Comment: @PraJazz windows also have [global variables](https://www.howtogeek.com/51807/how-to-create-and-use-global-system-environment-variables/)

Comment: @PraJazz and the answer linked by praveen also propose an [answer for windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47737354/10153945)

Comment: Check that casper PATH is set to "`X:path/to/casperjs/bin`". I had the same issue, and it was a CasperJS path mistake.